# Cannot encrypt .tar file in my Raspberry

Tags: linux, encryption, tar, gnupg

I'm tryng to encrypt a tar file using a password stored in a file: `~/Documents/Secret/.secret` using the following command:

```
cat ~/Documents/Secret/.secret | gpg -c --passphrase-fd 0 ~/backup.tar
```

Now I expect in output this file: `~/backup.tar.gpg` but it doesn't output anything.

I receive this error, someone can help me? I'm actually lost:

```
gpg: problem with the agent: ioctl non appropriata per il device
gpg: error creating passphrase: Operazione annullata
gpg: symmetric encryption of '/home/pi/backup.tar' failed: Operazione annullata
```

I'm trying to encrypt this file on my raspberry pi 3 with Raspian 9 (Stretch)

Comment: Have you tried the equivalent `gpg -c --passphrase-fd 0 ~/backup.tar <~/Documents/Secret/.secret` or `gpg -c --passphrase-file ~/Documents/Secret/.secret ~/backup.tar`?

Comment: The first gives me the same problem as before while the second asks me for a passphrase, so they both don't work

Answer (score 0):

The correct command to encrypt one file using a passphrase stored in a file is:

```
gpg -c --batch --yes --passphrase-file ~/Documents/Secret/.secret --output ~/backup.tar.gpg ~/backup.tar
```

Where:

- `-c` Encrypt the file
- `--batch` Is what I was looking for: Allowed me to execute the crypting process in a script
- `--yes` Confirm many messages in case of request (like: "Do you wanna ovewrite?")
- `--passphrase-file myKey` Indicates where the key is stored
- `--output` cryptedFile.gpg` Indicates the output name

Answer (score 0):

You should probably really use the `--pinentry-mode loopback` option, it allows passphrases in files and pipes (file descriptors).

The `--batch` and `--yes` commands take away a lot of your options and introduce risks, not the least of which is overwriting existing files. `--output` wouldn't be needed  then either, new files automatically get the `.gpg` extenson.

(IMO both are just workarounds for bugs introduced by forced pinentry programs).